# Genetic Programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lisp, dsl, genetic-programming

There is GenProg (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/genprog) for example, but that only deals with numerical optimization, in this case finding an equation that describes the data.

But I require for loops, if statements, when statements, Boolean checks etc. I need to be able to generate imperative structures. Any thought on this? My best options so far seem to be husk-scheme where I can run Scheme code as a DSL in Haskell. Surely there must be better ways?

Comment: Well, if you can formulate it in a monad, then you can use functions from `Control.Monad` like `forM`, `when`, `guard` if you have `MonadPlus`, etc.  What exactly is the problem with doing this in Haskell?  You just need a structure that can represent the kinds of equations you are trying to generate.

Comment: I doubt that there is a problem with doing this in Haskell, it's just that I seem to have difficulties with it. I have no idea how to generate monadic structures from within Haskell and then run them using an equivalent of `eval`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the kind of structure you're wanting to generate?  Even just a more precise and technical description of what you're trying to accomplish?  Are you wanting something like a tree that represents a complex algebraic equation?  These sorts of things are relatively easy to construct and manipulate in Haskell, and you have the advantage that the type system will restrict what a valid tree is.

Comment: What I want is to get is imperative code that is generated. The generated code is manipulated using genetic programming techniques. In pseudo code it would look something like the following: `if object.xcoord < someInt then rotate someInt degrees; while object.distance > someInt move someInt cm;` Also being able to use for loops, when etc.

Comment: It won't be quite the same as that in Haskell.  If you're not terribly familiar with the control structures in this language and how to perform stateful operations, I would highly recommend checking out [Learn You a Haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) and [Real Word Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/), both of which are available online for free and provide a pretty solid (if slightly dated due to GHC's rapid development) introduction to the core concepts of Haskell programming.

Comment: Please look at the answer already given. Bheklir is giving a specific answer to what imho is a specific question. Please reconsider getting this topic off the on hold status.

Answer (score 13):

If you're looking for something akin to S-expressions, this is fairly easily modeled in Haskell.  Say, for example, we want to represent simple algebraic equations with variables, such as

```hs
x + 5 / (y * 2 - z)
```

This can be represented by a simple AST in Haskell, in particular we can implement it as

```hs
data Expr
    = Lit Double        -- Literal numbers
    | Var Char          -- Variables have single letter names
    | Add Expr Expr     -- We can add things together
    | Sub Expr Expr     -- And subtract them
    | Mul Expr Expr     -- Why not multiply, too?
    | Div Expr Expr     -- And divide
    deriving (Eq)
```

This would let us express the equation above as

```hs
Add (Var 'x') (Div (Lit 5) (Sub (Mul (Var 'y') (Lit 2)) (Var 'z')))
```

But this is rather clunky to write and difficult to read.  Let's start by working some `Show` magic so that it gets pretty printed:

```hs
instance Show Expr where
    showsPrec n (Lit x)   = showParen (n > 10) $ showsPrec 11 x
    showsPrec n (Var x)   = showParen (n > 10) $ showChar x
    showsPrec n (Add x y) = showParen (n >  6) $ showsPrec 7 x . showString " + " . showsPrec 7 y
    showsPrec n (Sub x y) = showParen (n >  6) $ showsPrec 7 x . showString " - " . showsPrec 7 y
    showsPrec n (Mul x y) = showParen (n >  7) $ showsPrec 8 x . showString " * " . showsPrec 8 y
    showsPrec n (Div x y) = showParen (n >  7) $ showsPrec 8 x . showString " / " . showsPrec 8 y
```

If you don't understand everything going on here, that's ok, it's a lot of complication made easy by some built in functions for efficiently building strings with parentheses in them properly and all that fun stuff.  It's pretty much copied out of the docs in `Text.Show`.  Now if we print out our expression from above, it'll look like

```hs
x + 5.0 / (y * 2.0 - z)
```

Now for simplifying building these expressions.  Since they're pretty much numeric, we can implement `Num` (except for `abs` and `signum`) and `Fractional`:

```hs
instance Num Expr where
    fromInteger = Lit . fromInteger
    (+) = Add
    (-) = Sub
    (*) = Mul
    abs = undefined
    signum = undefined

instance Fractional Expr where
    (/) = Div
    fromRational = Lit . fromRational
```

Now we can input out expression from above as

```hs
Var 'x' + 5 / (Var 'y' * 2 - Var 'z')
```

This is at least much easier to visually parse, even if we have to specify the variables manually.

Now that we have pretty input and output, let's focus on evaluating these expressions.  Since we have variables in here, we'll need some sort of environment that associates a variable with a value

```hs
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Env = Map Char Double
```

And now it's just basic pattern matching (along with a helper function)

```hs
import Control.Applicative

binOp :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Expr -> Expr -> Env -> Maybe Double
binOp op x y vars = op <$> evalExpr x vars <*> evalExpr y vars

evalExpr :: Expr -> Env -> Maybe Double
evalExpr (Lit x)   = const $ Just x
evalExpr (Var x)   = M.lookup x
evalExpr (Add x y) = binOp (+) x y
evalExpr (Sub x y) = binOp (-) x y
evalExpr (Mul x y) = binOp (*) x y
evalExpr (Div x y) = binOp (/) x y
```

Now we can use `evalExpr` to evaluate an expression in our mini-language with variable substitution.  All the error handling if there's an undefined variable is done by the `Maybe` monad, and we were even able to cut down on repetition by making the environment argument implicit.  This is all pretty standard for a simple expression DSL.

---

So for the fun bit, generating random expressions and (eventually) mutations.  For this, we'll need `System.Random`.  We want to be able to generate expressions of varying complexity, so we'll express it in rough depth.  Since it's random, there is a chance that we'll get shorter or deeper trees than specified.  This will probably be something that you'll want to tweak and tune to get your desired results.  First, because I have the foresight of having written this code already, let's define two helpers for generating a random literal and a random variable:

```hs
randomLit, randomVar :: IO Expr
randomLit = Lit <$> randomRIO (-100, 100)
randomVar = Var <$> randomRIO ('x',  'z')
```

Nothing exciting here, we get doubles between -100 and 100, and up to 3 variables.  Now we can generate large expression trees.

```hs
generateExpr :: Int -> IO Expr
-- When the depth is 1, return a literal or a variable randomly
generateExpr 1 = do
    isLit <- randomIO
    if isLit
        then randomLit
        else randomVar
-- Otherwise, generate a tree using helper
generateExpr n = randomRIO (0, 100) >>= helper
    where
        helper :: Int -> IO Expr
        helper prob
            -- 20% chance that it's a literal
            | prob < 20  = randomLit
            -- 10% chance that it's a variable
            | prob < 30  = randomVar
            -- 15% chance of Add
            | prob < 45  = (+) <$> generateExpr (n - 1) <*> generateExpr (n - 1)
            -- 15% chance of Sub
            | prob < 60  = (-) <$> generateExpr (n - 1) <*> generateExpr (n - 1)
            -- 15% chance of Mul
            | prob < 75  = (*) <$> generateExpr (n - 1) <*> generateExpr (n - 1)
            -- 15% chance of Div
            | prob < 90  = (/) <$> generateExpr (n - 1) <*> generateExpr (n - 1)
            -- 10% chance that we generate a possibly taller tree
            | otherwise = generateExpr (n + 1)
```

The bulk of this function is just specifying the probabilities that a given node will be generated, and then generating the left and right nodes for each operator.  We even got to use the normal arithmetic operators since we overloaded `Num`, how handy!

---

Now, remember that we can still pattern match on the constructors of this `Expr` type for other operations, such as replacing nodes, swapping them, or measuring the depth.  For this, you just have to treat it as any other binary tree type in Haskell, except it has 2 leaf constructors and 4 node constructors.  As for mutations, you'll have to write code that traverses this structure and chooses when to swap out nodes and what to swap them out with.  It'll live within the `IO` monad since you'll be generating random values, but it shouldn't be too difficult.  This structure should be pretty easy to extend as need be, such as if you wanted to add trig functions and exponentiation, you'd just need more constructors, more expressions in `evalExpr`, and the appropriate clauses in `helper`, along with some probability adjustments.

You can get the full code for this example [here](https://gist.github.com/609ebd2073c6342827b6).  Hope this helps you see how to formulate something like S-expressions in Haskell.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the extensive answer! I get this part of the code and it is part of what I require. What you do here is finding a mathematical function that describes relationships between variables. This is an important part of what I am trying to do. But there is also a part with control structures that I am still not capable of doing. For example, with your code it is possible to create: `x+22/4-y`. What is also needed is (for example) `if x+22/4-y < someInt then doAction`. Do you have an idea on that?

Comment: @Robotijn Well, you'll have to do things like `case evalExpr some_expr varMap of { Nothing -> handleFailure; Just x -> when x < someInt then doAction }`, or you can use a better monad for working with `IO` and `Maybe`s, like [`MaybeT IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MaybeT)